# Osmnx: How to exclude streets from city graph

Tags: osmnx

I am trying to remove the outer ring of a city (Paris in my case) from the city graph which I obtained with osmnx:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place("Paris, Ile-de-France, France", network_type="drive")
```

I am aware that one can build a graph around a certain street (`ox.graph_from_address()`), however I need the graph of the whole city, just without the outer ring and want to remove  streets in the outskirts from the network as well.

Is there a way to do this with osmnx?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Elena. Could you be more precise about your problem statement? What exactly are the 'whole city', 'outer ring' and 'outskirts'?

Comment: In the case of Paris, I refer to the Boulevard Peripherique with the 'outer ring'.
With 'outskirts' I mean streets outside this ring, i.e. the green area in the south-east, starting with Parc zoologique de Paris.
I am interested in everything inside the Boulevard Peripherique and am wondering whether there's a way to remove parts beyond a certain boundary from a city with osmnx.

Comment: Yes. You just need a polygon representing the ring you want to remove and then you can use OSMnx's `truncate` module. Alternatively, you can use a polygon representing the parts of the city you *do* want and then use the `graph_from_polygon` function to model it.